# Insert in Binary Serach Tree Unhandled exception thrown

Tags: c++, tree, binary

I have a function to insert nodes in a binary search tree. I get a crash when I try to insert a node. I use the debugger from VS and it tells me Unhandled exception thrown: write access violation.
m_father was nullptr.

Here is my function to insert:

```
NOD *INSERT(NOD k)
{
    NOD *temp = new NOD(k);
    NOD *m_father = NULL;
    NOD *x = root;
    while (x != NULL)
    {
        m_father = x;
        if (m_father->m_key > x->m_key)
        {
            x = x->m_right_child;
        }
        x = x->m_left_child;
    }
    if (root == NULL) 
        root = temp;
    else if (temp->m_right_child->m_key > m_father->m_key)
        {
            m_father->m_right_child = temp;
        }
    m_father->m_left_child = temp;
    temp->m_father = m_father;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is how i try to insert a node:

```
int temp_nod;
cin >> temp_nod;
binary_tree.INSERT(temp_nod);
```

Comment: "Unhandled exception" means you have a *crash*. The first step toward solving crashes is to catch them in a debugger to locate when and where they happen in your code, and examine all involved variables and their value.

Comment: I'm also a little worried about your use if the *local* variable `m_father`. It seems you use the `m_` prefix for member variables, but you still declare a local variable with that same prefix.

Comment: Furthermore, in the first loop you *unconditionally* have the assignment `x = x->m_left_child`. That's probably not correct. You should probably [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) more generally.

Comment: Yeah, the debugger it tells "m_father was nullptr." and the line with the problem is m_father->m_left_child=temp; but i don't know what should i change.

Comment: And lastly, you have `temp->m_right_child->m_key` in a condition, but have you properly copied `k`? Do your copy-constructor works as intended? And considering you have a copy-constructor (or at least use one) and pass `k` by value, do you follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? And please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: Oh I just noticed... `binary_tree.INSERT(temp_nod);` where `temp_nod` is an `int`. What *is* the type of `NOD`? Is it an alias for `int`? If not, doesn't the compiler complain? Again, ***please*** create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: You should probably also [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), read [this Stack Overflow checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/), and all of http://idownvotedbecau.se/ (like for example http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ or http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/).

Comment: @dxerok *but i don't know what should i change* -- Before writing any code like this, you should have drawn on paper a binary tree, and various insert scenarios using boxes and lines, thus then you would have a plan on how to insert a node.  Then you write the code, following the plan.  If the code does not work, then you see where in the code the logic diverts from your plan, thus you make adjustments to the code to follow the plan, or you throw the plan away and start over with a new plan.  Not knowing what to change indicates you must have skipped these steps and just wanted to write code.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

```
else if (temp->m_right_child->m_key > m_father->m_key)
```

`temp` is copy-constructed here (is it the expected behaviour?). If it's created from a new node, `m_right_child` might not be assigned yet, so you try to dereference a `nullptr`.
I'm not sure, but you did you want to check `temp` key here? I don't see much reason to check child key when choosing the correct place in BST.

Also, as noted in the comments, you assign m_father->left_child **always**, without a condition. This happens even in an empty list, so again we try to dereference a `nullptr`. I suppose it should look more like this:

```
if (root == NULL) 
    root = temp;
else if (temp->m_right_child->m_key > m_father->m_key)
{
    m_father->m_right_child = temp;
    temp->m_father = m_father;
}
else
{
    m_father->m_left_child = temp;
    temp->m_father = m_father;
}
```

As a side note, if your function does not return anything useful, just make it `void`.

Comment: Yes it's new, but it's constructed by copy-construction, so we don't really know what `m_right_child` might be.

Comment: True that. I'm editing my answer, including also the other possible `nullptr`s

Answer (score 0):

If `root == NULL` the only assignment to `m_father` would be `NOD *m_father = NULL;`, before the statement `m_father->m_left_child = temp;`.

EDIT: (Because if `root == NULL`, then `x` would also be `NULL`, so the `while` loop would not be executed)

EDIT2: `else if (temp->m_right_child->m_key > m_father->m_key)` => `m_father->m_left_child = temp;` - the former will not be evaluated if `root == NULL`, since it is an `else if` to an `if` that was true.